# What partition key and row key is best for tweet-like data?

Tags: azure, nosql, schema

I am designing a mobile service on Windows Azure with table storage. I am storing tweet-like objects to generate a user feed (again, like twitter with follows). Taking into account that I should only query the partition key and row key, what should they be for a chronological feed that only gets the tweet-like objects that a user follows?

As a bonus, how could I also search these by hash tag (again knowing that I am only limited to partition key and row key)?

Note: I have a following table to get whether a user follows another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the only indexing is supported on PartitionKey/Row, **`the basic idea is to denormalize the data based on how you're going to search on that data`**. What that would mean is that you would end up storing same data across multiple tables. There could be many designs possible for what you're trying to accomplish. I'm outlining one which I could think of :).

> I am designing a mobile service on Windows Azure with table storage. I
>   am storing tweet-like objects to generate a user feed (again, like
>   twitter with follows). Taking into account that I should only query
>   the partition key and row key, what should they be for a chronological
>   feed that only gets the tweet-like objects that a user follows?

Let's assume that each user in your system gets a GUID as a unique user identifier. Now to accomplish what you're trying to do, there could be many approaches. In all the approaches, you would need a table which maintains a list of users a user follows. Let's call this table as `PeopleIFollow`. This table would have:

PartitionKey = Id of the user

RowKey = Id of the user you follow

Now coming to getting user feeds:

**Have a centralized table for all feeds**:

To accomplish this, you would need a table which will store all feeds. Let's call it `Feeds`. Since you're only interested in getting latest feeds for a user, in this table:

PartitionKey = Feed date/time in UTC Ticks up to seconds precision (you can decide on the precision based on your requirements)

RowKey = Id of the user who posted.

You would then first dip into `PeopleIFollow` and get the list of users and then dip into this table to get feeds from the users for last `x` seconds.

**Have a feed table for each user:**

In this approach, each user feed goes into a separate table. Let's name this table as `Feeds<UserId>`. In this table,

PartitionKey = Feed date/time in UTC Ticks up to seconds precision (you can decide on the precision based on your requirements)

RowKey = a unique identifier for the feed.

First you would dip into this table and find out the list of users a user follow and then for each user you would dip into individual feeds table and fetch the data for last `x` seconds.

> As a bonus, how could I also search these by hash tag (again knowing
>   that I am only limited to partition key and row key)?

Again you would need to have a table where you would associate hash tags with posts. So if we assume that each post is saved in a table called `Posts` with PartitionKey = some id to identify a post, you could have a table called `HashTags` with:

PartitionKey = hash tag

RowKey = Id of the post

In this scenario, first you would find all the post ids from `HashTags` table and then dip into `Posts` table to fetch the details about that post.

Obviously with all these approaches, you would need to think about how you're going to save data across multiple tables/partitions (thus transactions are out of picture) and other things. For storing date/time values, you may want to consider storing data in reverse chronolical order (using DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks) so that latest entries are always on top.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I have been playing around with date and time and had actually used the structure you suggested for the follows. Your method involves duplicating data which I guess is not so bad when it comes to cheap NoSQL storage.